# Extra constraints on columns not appeared in GROUP BY without JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

Consider the following table:

```
Company     BuildYear   ProductName   Cost
------    -----------   -----------   ----
  Foo         1900          A_1        50
  Foo         2000          B_1        50
  Foo         2000          B_2        50

  Bar         1900          A_1        50
  Bar         1900          A_2        100
  Bar         2000          B_1        50
```

Query #1 (easy):

We are looking for **companies which produced only one kind of product in 1900**. In the example above it would be only company `Foo` with A_1 product (company `Bar` produced two different type products, namely A_1 and A_2)

For this, the query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE BuildYear=1900
GROUP BY ProductName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Query #2 (my problem):

Now we are looking for **companies which produced only one kind of product in 1900, and that one product costs less than 75**. For the sample table above, the answer would be again only the `Foo` company.

Needless to say, simply adding `AND cost<75` to the above query returns the wrong answer (both `Foo` and `Bar`). Also adding it to `HAVING` clause raises the error message below:

> Column "Cost" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

On the other hand, I'd rather no to join the result of the above query with the original table again (if possible) as the table is huge in reality.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** columns shown above are just for demonstration and in the real tables they are all `TEXT` (so MIN/MAX trick doesn't apply)

**Update:** why doesn't adding `AND cost<75` to `WHERE` clause work? Because this clause cut off the `Bar::A_2` product and when afterwards `HAVING` is evaluating, it considers `Bar` as a company with one product.

Comment: Not sure I understand everything yet, but shouldn't you simply be able include `and cost < 75` in your where clause? BTW, it sure looks to me like Foo has two rows in 1900.

Comment: I fixed the latter point. I'll elaborate on why a simple and doesn't work in a min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one product, then you can use `MIN()` or `MAX()` -- they have the same value if there is only one row in the group:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE BuildYear = 1900
GROUP BY ProductName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MIN(COST) < 75;
```

If you are storing numbers as text you should fix your data.

Barring that, just convert it:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MIN(COST::NUMERIC) < 75;
```

Comment: Not applicable to my problem. I added an update to my question. Please read.

Comment: @Emadpres . . . Of course, `MIN()` and `MAX()` work on text types.  I have no idea what your issue is, unless you are storing a number as text.

Comment: Oh, cool! I didn't know! is it a hack, or it's fine to use them with text?

Comment: It works, but you need to cast it to a number (as in Gordon's second example).  Otherwise it won't work correctly.  As text, 100000000 will be "less" than 2.

Comment: There's an issue here with this solution. I tried it in my case and it seems not working when it is used as `AND MIN(...)='....'` code. The equality with another text no longer works when it passed through `MIN` function, right?

Comment: @Emadpres . . . For equality, you can use `=`, but you might have trailing spaces or hidden characters that pose a problem.  For a numeric comparison, you need to convert the value to a number (as shown in the answer now).  The real solution is to fix your data so numbers are stored with the correct type.  I'm just confused because the code `cost < 75` comes directly from your question.  You seemed comfortable using it there.